# Coq Extraction: Permission Denied

Tags: macos, coq, coqide, coq-extraction

When I execute the following commands within the CoqIDE:

```
Extraction Language Haskell.
Extraction "Code.hs" my_function.
```

I get the following error:

```
System error: "Code.hs: Permission denied"
```

If I try instead:

```
Extraction Language Haskell.
Extraction "~/Code.hs"  example10.
```

I get the error:

```
System error: "~/Code.hs: No such file or directory"
```

I'm using the CoqIDE 8.5beta3 for MacOSX.

How can I fix this? How can I do extraction through the CoqIDE without having permission issues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably trying to write to a directory to which you don't have write permission, so it is not a Coq error, but an error from your operating system.

The second reason is probably that Coq does not expand the `~` to your home directory.  It is a `bash`ism, not an OS thing.  Write `/Users/yourname/` instead.

Comment: I tried with `/User/myname/` instead of `~`, and the problem is the same. Do you have any other ideas, @larsr ?

Comment: Oh, yes. It worked now.  I just wonder why the extraction mechanism in Coq(IDE) forces us to specify an absolute path to the file where the extracted code should be saved. I wish that, by default, it simply saved the extracted code in the same directory of the ".v" file.